# Get this simple xpath

Tags: html, xpath

I need to get the `<td> 318 - BANCO BMG </td>` from the next to last line of the code. It dynamically changes from client to client but the `<label class="hint" data-hint="CARTÃO RMC">RMC</label>` or `fa fa-credit-card` will always be there.

I'm new programming and now I'm struggling with this html to get the right xpath. Already read about "advanced" xpaths and get most of them when I need, but can't deal with this one.

```
<tbody>
   <tr class="">
      <td>
         <center><i class="fa fa-dollar-sign" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#11b336;"></i></center>
      </td>
      <td>
         <label class="hint" data-hint="EMPRÉSTIMO CONSIGNADO">CONSIGNAÇÃO</label>                                                                              
      </td>
      <td>
         341 - ITAU                                                                             
      </td>

   <tr class="">
      <td>
         <center><i class="fa fa-dollar-sign" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#11b336;"></i></center>
      </td>
      <td>
         <label class="hint" data-hint="EMPRÉSTIMO CONSIGNADO">CONSIGNAÇÃO</label>                                                                              
      </td>
      <td>
         707 - DAYCOVAL                                                                             
      </td>

   <tr class="">
      <td>
         <center><i class="fa fa-credit-card" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#3f88b5;"></i></center>
      </td>
      <td>
         <label class="hint" data-hint="CARTÃO RMC">RMC</label>                                                                             
      </td>
      <td>
         318 - BANCO BMG                                                                                
      </td>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: With `//*[@id="tab_contrato"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]` I can get the `td` I want but not excluding the other ones... With `//*[@id="tab_contrato"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/label[@class="hint"][not(contains(@data-hint, "CARTÃO RMC"))]` I can select the all the ones that I don't want but I could not get what I want with even with `contains`

Comment: Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using parent nad following-sibling... I was struggling because I was using something like forward-sibling

```
//*[@id="tab_contrato"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/label[@class="hint"][not(contains(@data-hint, "CARTÃO RMC"))]//parent::td/following-sibling::td[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter XPath would be :

```
//table//label[.="RMC"]/following::td[1]
```

Output : 318 - BANCO BMG